# Cursor in android studio select rectangle area

Tags: android

My cursor have some issue when i select area. It not select from right to left, from bottom to top, it seem to be select rectangle area. my problem is showed in below picture.

[image]

I don't know whether i have set something. Please help me to fix it?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you are using Windows use this :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to switch into selection mode.

**Update**

For Mac :

<kbd>Shitf</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Go to your android studio go right click and select column selection mode

[SEE IT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULfQj.png)